# Cassandra won't start

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra is installed in one node system. and system is clashed for unknown reason.

afterward, cassandra daemon won't start. I erased and reinstalled cassandra but it not helps. Here's the log.

```
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,609 JMXServerUtils.java:249 - Configured JMX server at: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,660 CassandraDaemon.java:471 - Hostname: master
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,660 CassandraDaemon.java:478 - JVM vendor/version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_151
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,698 CassandraDaemon.java:479 - Heap size: 1004.000MiB/1004.000MiB
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,699 CassandraDaemon.java:484 - Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 4491328(4386K) committed = 4521984(4416K) max = 251658240(245760K)
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,699 CassandraDaemon.java:484 - Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 19393984(18939K) committed = 19922944(19456K) max = -1(-1K)
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,699 CassandraDaemon.java:484 - Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 2216400(2164K) committed = 2359296(2304K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,700 CassandraDaemon.java:484 - Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 167772160(163840K) used = 97386712(95104K) committed = 167772160(163840K) max = 167772160(163840K)
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,700 CassandraDaemon.java:484 - Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 20971520(20480K) used = 0(0K) committed = 20971520(20480K) max = 20971520(20480K)
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,700 CassandraDaemon.java:484 - CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 864026624(843776K) used = 0(0K) committed = 864026624(843776K) max = 864026624(843776K)
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,700 CassandraDaemon.java:486 - Classpath: :/usr/java/jdk_7.0_80/lib/-:/usr/java/jdk_7.0_80/jre/lib/-:/usr/java/jdk_7.0_80/jre/lib/ext/-:.:/etc/cassandra/conf:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/airline-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/asm-5.0.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/caffeine-2.2.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrent-trees-2.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-18.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/hppc-0.5.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/javax.inject.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jctools-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jflex-1.6.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jna-4.2.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/joda-time-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jstackjunit-0.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-3.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-jvm-3.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-logback-3.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ohc-core-0.4.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ohc-core-j8-0.4.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config3-3.0.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-base-3.0.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/sigar-1.6.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snowball-stemmer-1.3.0.581.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-3.11.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar::/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar
INFO  [main] 2017-11-24 05:16:40,700 CassandraDaemon.java:488 - JVM Arguments: [-Xloggc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log, -ea, -XX:+UseThreadPriorities, -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xss256k, -XX:StringTableSize=1000003, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -XX:-UseBiasedLocking, -XX:+UseTLAB, -XX:+ResizeTLAB, -XX:+UseNUMA, -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000, -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled, -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10, -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M, -Xms1024M, -Xmx1024M, -Xmn200M, -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/cassandra/conf/hotspot_compiler, -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password, -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/cassandra/lib/sigar-bin, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra, -Dcassandra.storagedir=, -Dcassandra-foreground=yes]
Killed
```

Comment: did you get any clue in debug.log ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` after the service start?

If you ran with `cassandra -f`  first you may of created files with your user instead of the cassandra user which would cause permission issues when service starts.